# Why does segmentation fault occur even if I am just checking an "Out Of Bound" value and not accessing it

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

```
bool isValid(int x, int y, vector<vector<int>> &arr)
{

  if (x >= 0 && x <= arr.size() && y >= 0 && y <= arr[0].size() && arr[x][y] == 1)
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

1. I am getting segmentation fault on this ( x <= arr.size() and y<=arr[0].size() ) of the code.
2. Can you guys please explain why I am getting this even if I am not accessing the out of bound value and I am just comparing it.

Comment: What if `x` is zero and `arr` is empty?

Comment: *Can you guys please explain why I am getting this even if I am not accessing the out of bound value* --  You are accessing the value.  This is undefined behavior, regardless of the type of access.

Comment: the last valid index is `size - 1`, your check `x <= arr.size()` is off by 1, should be `x < arr.size()`

Comment: Then you have the `y` issue.  What if `arr[0]` itself is empty?  Maybe it would be easier to break up that `if` statement into two separate `if` statements, where the first checks for empty? --`if (!arr.empty() && !arr[0].empty())`

Comment: Now I got it thank you guys very much

Answer (score 1):

What if `x == 0` and `arr.size() == 0`?

In this case, you'll fail on accessing `arr[0]` inside the `y <= arr[0].size()` expression, because you are trying to access the vector object present in `arr[0]` while such thing does not exist.

To be more general, you have to note that accessing `arr[x][y]` is not valid if `x == arr.size()` or `y == arr[x].size()`, but you're allowing such situation by `x <= arr.size()` and `y <= arr[0].size()` in your conditions. Your function would finally look like something like this:

```
bool isValid(int x, int y, vector<vector<int>> &arr)
{
  if (x >= 0 && x < arr.size() && y >= 0 && y < arr[x].size() && arr[x][y] == 1)
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: It isn't only `x == 0` being the problem.  They compare `x <= arr.size()`.  What if `x == arr.size()`?

Answer (score 1):

Packing too many conditions into one is not always good. Splitting it up in several conditions can help with debugging. Simple code is not always less code.

```
bool isValid(int x, int y, vector<vector<int>> &arr) {
      // first index is ok?
      if (x < 0) return false; 
      if (x >= arr.size()) return false;
      // only now you can access arr[x]
      if (y < 0) return false;
      if (y >= arr[x].size()) return false;
      // both are ok
      return arr[x][y] == 1;
}
```

In your code you are checking `arr[0]` not `arr[x]`, when all inner vectors are of same size you can consider to use a different data structure. Even when you know that all inner vectors of same size you should nevertheless check `arr[x]` not `arr[0]`. Also consider to use `size_t` (it is `unsigned`) for the indices, then you can remove the checks for `<0`.

Your code can segfault because the last valid index is `size -1` not `size` and because `arr[0]` does not necessarily have same number of elements as `arr[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

> why I am getting this even if I am not accessing the out of bound value and I am just comparing it [?]

Consider `y <= arr[0].size()`, here you are not just comparing, but accessing the first element of `arr` and retrieving its size. The problem is that `arr` may be empty, so that `arr[0]` would be an access out of bounds.

Also, using `<=` is an off-by-one error, because `size() - 1` is the last valid index.

That function could be rewritten like the following

```cpp
bool isValid(int x, int y, std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& m)
{
    return x >= 0  and  x < m.size()  and
    //                    ^
           y >= 0  and  y < m[x].size()  and
    //                    ^  ^^^              Are all the same size?
           m[x][y] == 1;
}
```